# Linking to downloadable files

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a policy for or against providing executables and other self hosted downloads?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4716/is-there-a-policy-for-or-against-providing-executables-and-other-self-hosted-dow)

I answered a question earlier about group policy and I stated that they could use Windows SteadyState to achieve this. However this morning I found the installer on my computer and uploaded it to Mediafire, but I had second thoughts about posting links to applications.

So my question is, is it acceptable to link to applications that I have uploaded myself? Or is this frowned upon/not allowed?

Comment: [Is there a policy for or against providing executables and other self hosted downloads?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4716/is-there-a-policy-for-or-against-providing-executables-and-other-self-hosted-dow)

Comment: Note for context: Microsoft no longer provides a Windows SteadyState download, because the product has been discontinued.